# Rails validators discrepancy between presence and format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a model that takes an email address, but I do not want to require it for instance creation. I tried the following:

```
validates :email, :presence => false, :format => { :with => email_regex }
```

But this fails my test suite, the format regex apparently makes the presence of the email attribute required.

I thought it might be possible with a `before_save` method: is it possible to reject saving the object in a `before_save` method? Is there a better, "Rails way" of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:allow_blank` (or `:allow_nil`):

```
validates :email, :allow_blank => true, :format => { :with => email_regex }
```